# Multiple Laravel project htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have a problem with .htaccess configuration for multiple Laravel projects on my Apache webserver. One project in the root folder and one project in a subfolder

**File structure (/www)**

```
/ <-- Laravel application #1
/anotherProject <-- Laravel application #2
```

When I'm visiting [www.example.com/anotherProject](http://www.example.com/anotherProject) then I get a 404 error (and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is working. The following .htaccess is activate in /public/ (for Laravel application #1).

**/public/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It feels like I need to change something in the .htaccess file of the project in the root folder. Has someone a suggestion to try?

Comment: Does it work if you add an extra condition to the front controller part `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/anotherProject`?

Comment: @BadHorsie Thanks for responding. I already tried that, then the URL redirects to /public/anotherProject with an 404 error. :-(